# Magento Customer Account hide order status

Tags: magento, status

We don't use the various order statuses in Magento as we send invoices and shipping notifications from external software to customers.

Therefore I would like to hide the column "status" for customers in their account overview. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You're not "hiding" an order status, you want to show a previous status rather than a current status under certain circumstances. Effectively you want to have a current public status and a current backend status. That's a significant change.

Rather than introducing two separate statuses into a system that is built around having just one, you could more easily solve this issue by having separate language on frontend and backend.

The frontend text for statuses A and B would be the same. The backend text for statuses A and B would be different.

This assumes that there is a definite link between the two statuses, and that the public always appear to still see status A if it's status B.

For example, if status A is "Preparing pizza", and status B is "Removing all signs of having dropped pizza on floor", this would be fine. But if you sometimes wanted to use status B while displaying status C "Pizza is on the bike", you'd have to split that status too.

As a result, it will definitely be advisable to keep the public status within the backend language, so status B would read "Preparing pizza [Removing all signs of having dropped pizza on floor]".

Another way to approach this would be to find a way of communicating Status B that is appropriate to the customer - eg customer sees "Quality Control", backend sees "Checking for mouse droppings".

If you are fiddling with language, be careful that emails don't send the backend language by mistake.

The non-programming solution is to just have one status frontend and back that is a euphemism for the desired status but appears innocuous to the customer.

another way,

FTP into your site and get a copy of app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml

In Magento 1.7, go to line 1305. 
You see tags for 1

Change that 1 to a 0

If there is no 1, add it to any status you’d like to hide.

FTP the file back into your app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/

Test the frontend to verify the statuses have been hidden

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already found these two things while searching but it is not what I want. I want don't want to show any statuses in customer account view as I don't close order after invoicing and it is confusing for customers if there is still to see "pending" or "on hold". I just want to hide the column "status"

Answer (score 0):

You just need to comment out the column from the respective phtml file

If you are using magento 1.9 rwd theme,
1) navigate to app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/sales/order/recent.phtml

If you are using magento version < 1.9 ,
1) navigate to app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales/order/recent.phtml

2) comment out line no 47 and line no 58

Note: Step 2 is common for both. 
Hope this helps :)

Comment: Can you specify what is in the lines that you are saying to comment out?  Otherwise, this not helpful for other Magento versions.

Comment: <th class="status"><?php echo $this->__('Status') ?></th> and <td class="status"><em><?php echo $_order->getStatusLabel() ?></em></td>